# How Can I Connect to remote sql server?

Tags: connection, remote

I have a desktop application(Developed in c#) which will use SQL SERVER database. The database is on remote Database Server. I need to connect to that database on this database server and some transaction with this database.

I have the internet connection. I know the ip address and port number of sql server in this database server.

So what are the steps to connect to that database server?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO: it is not secure to have sql server listening on public ip address! You should use a vpn or at least a ssh tunnel.

Anyway, try to create an alias with ip address, in the MSSQL Client configuration utilty.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a connection string in your App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
       <add name="nameOfThisConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=databaseserver; Initial Catalog=database;User Id=username;Password=password"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you can use the connection string to execute commands:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nameOfThisConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString );
connection.Open(); 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from members", connection);
int amount= (int)(command.ExecuteScalar());
labelamount.Text = amount.ToString() + " records";
connection.Close();
```

Thats about it.
You can also use other query's like:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nameOfThisConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString );
connection.Open(); 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from Contact order by Name", connection);
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dataReader.Read())
    { 
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dataReader["ID"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dataReader["Name"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dataReader["Email"].ToString());
        listViewContacts.Items.Add(item);
    }   
dataReader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

With these 2 commands you should be able to get it work.